# Prestashop custom module controller

Tags: module, url-rewriting, prestashop-1.6

I have an issue, I have created module which makes link to `hookDisplayCustomerAaccount`

with

```
$this->context->smarty->assign(
  array(
    'array_data' => $array,
    'link_to_mymodule' => $this->context->link->getModuleLink('mymodule', 'display'),
  )
);
return $this->display(__FILE__, 'myaccountlink.tpl');
```

in myaccountlink.tpl I have made link with `<a href="{$link_to_mymodule}"`....

I have in modules/mymodule/controllers/front/display.php :

```
class mymoduledisplayModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
  public function initContent()
  {
    parent::initContent();
    $this->setTemplate('display.tpl');
  }
}
```

and in my module root folder display.tpl with random text.

However, when I click the link in my account page, it tries to go to `my url.com/module/mymodule/display` and I get 500 server error, oops something went wrong ... page. No php errors in log tho :/

Comment: I can't test atm but from the top of my head I think you need to put `display.tpl` inside `yourmodulefolder/templates/views/front`.

Comment: No luck with that either

Comment: Then you need to enable debug mode to see what error you're getting.

Comment: Everything seems to be correct as per your shared code. Can you check errors with debug mode as enabled.

FYI, to enable error debugging you can follow the steps below.
- open file: config/defines.inc.php (using FTP or hosting control panel)
- change false-->true:
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);